# How do I add time from a database in Rails?

Tags: datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I am fairly new to rails, and attempting to add an amount of time to a datetime in the database. The time and time unit both are returned from the database.

So the data is...

```
start: 11/1/2015 10:45:00
duration: 75
unit: "minutes"
```

I want to add the 75 minutes to the start. I know I can do this if I know them already by saying start + 75.minutes, but how do I do this when both the duration and the unit are variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `send` method:

```
start + duration.send(unit)
```

Comment: ok, so the start and duration are part of a model called "event" - so it would actually have to be: @event.start + @event.duration.send(@event.unit) - would that work?

Comment: It will, assuming you have the `@event` object (e.g. fetched with `@event = Event.find(params[:id])`)

Comment: This is what I get in console: NoMethodError: undefined method `Minutes' for 75:Fixnum

Comment: It means `unit` is `"Minutes"` instead of `"minutes"`. You can easily fix it with `downcase` - `@event.start + @event.duration.send(@event.unit.downcase)`